# How to calculate the number of possible combinations fot a random stratifed population

Tags: sampling

I have divided a population wiofth 100 members into 10 strata and from each strata select one member to make up a random stratifed sample.  Is there a formula to compute the number of possible combinations as expexct this will be less than for simple random sampling

Comment: This would probably have been better posted on MathOverflow than this site.

Comment: Thanks - I did not realise such a site existed